# dpkg: error proccessing package archive install (--install)

Tags: apt, package-management

This is my terminal

```
$ sudo dpkg -i install /home/chowder/Downloads/okular.deb
dpkg: error processing archive install (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 233799 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chowder/Downloads/okular.deb ...
Unpacking okular (4:16.12.3-0ubuntu1) over (4:16.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up okular (4:16.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22+linuxmint1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install
```

`sudo dpkg -f install` and `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get update install` did not fix this

Answer (score 0):

The command is supposed to be `sudo dpkg -i /home/chowder/Downloads/okular.deb`. The `install` is not needed there and is meaningless.

Comment: worse is the `-i install` tried to install install.deb which it didn't find & produced the error "cannot access archive: no such file or directory" which confused @chowder3097 .   the `-i` means install which is the command; 'install' is used for high-level tools like `apt-get` or `apt`